# How can i open a shell without making it active?

Tags: java, shell, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I need to know if there is any way to open a shell and not make it active, even if i click a control in it. The best way to explain what i need is to show you this little example. I need to keep the first shell active, even if i click the second one, or any widget that it contains.

```
public class TestMeOut
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {

        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        final Shell shell2 = new Shell(shell);
        shell2.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Button btn = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        final Button btn2 = new Button(shell2, SWT.PUSH);

        btn.setText("Test me");
        btn2.setText("I steal focus");

        btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                shell2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        btn2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                shell2.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        shell.addShellListener(new ShellListener()
        {

            public void shellIconified(final ShellEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void shellDeiconified(final ShellEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void shellDeactivated(final ShellEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Deactivated! This isn't supposed to happen.");
            }

            public void shellClosed(final ShellEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void shellActivated(final ShellEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Activated!");
            }
        });

        shell2.pack();
        shell2.open();
        shell2.setVisible(false);

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the style of your second `Shell` and use `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` which will make sure that you cannot interact with the parent shell unless you close the child shell:

```
final Shell shell2 = new Shell(shell, SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

> The modality of an instance may be specified using style bits. The modality style bits are used to determine whether input is blocked for other shells on the display. The `PRIMARY_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to its parent. The `APPLICATION_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to every other shell in the display. The `SYSTEM_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to all shells, including shells belonging to different applications.

Even `SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL` would suffice in this case.

---

**UPDATE**

If on the other hand you don't want the parent to loose focus when the child is clicked, just disable the child:

```
shell2.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The first shell is still getting deactivated. I need it to stay active at all times.

Comment: @JNewbie So you want the parent to stay active and the child to be inactive?

Comment: Yes, and the parent should stay active even if i click on the child.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way i can click the button inside the child shell?(and still not deactivate the parent)

Comment: @JNewbie If you use `setEnabled(false)` then you can't interact with anything in the child shell. You could try (instead of disabling the child) to force the focus back to the parent shell after interaction with the child shell. It would be helpful to know why you want to do this. Why disallow interaction except for one button (may confuse the user).

Comment: I am trying to open a date picker from a combo and than input the selection from the picker into the combo as a formatted date. But when i click on the picker, the shell containing the combo deactivates.

Comment: @Baz should the setEnabled(false) also help with not stealing focus from inside the same application from where the new shell is launched?