# new SWT Shell without taking focus?

Tags: java, swt

currently developing an Eclipse plugin and I wanted to make a Shell that does not take focus while it's being created/shown.

I've tried using SWT.NO_FOCUS but to no avail.

How do you create a Shell without taking focus away from another app/window you are on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will open a new `Shell` without taking the focus off the parent:

```
final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setText("StackOverflow");
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Open new Shell");
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, (event) -> {
    Shell child = new Shell(shell);
    child.setText("Child");
    child.setVisible(true);
    child.setSize(300,200);
});

shell.pack();
shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed())
{
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

Comment: The way in which I was opening the shell was giving me trouble, I was using Shell.open(), instead of setVisible(true). Thanks for the sample.

Comment: @VladIlie Glad it worked for you. Was calling `open()` first as well, because that's what you usually do.

Answer (score 1):

For something like a tooltip shell use:

```
new Shell(parent, SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.TOOL | SWT.NO_FOCUS);
```

Comment: I've tried this constructor but focus is still taken away from other components in the GUI. I've also tried Baz's setEnable(false) suggestion from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120040/how-can-i-open-a-shell-without-making-it-active but that only seems to not steal focus from other applications.

Comment: Show us some code because this definitely works for tooltips.

Comment: I was using open() to show the Shell and that was setting focus on it, as per API. setVisible(true) instead helped. Thanks